# MySQL relational tables and Primary Keys data types

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I'm working on building a MySQL database that will have many related tables.  I know I can create a primary key that is unique and auto increments, then reference that Primary Key as a Foreign Key in the related table.  My question is what are best practices for Primary/Foreign key data types (int, varchar, etc..).  I want to make sure I get this right the first time.

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In MySQL most commonly used datatype is INT UNSIGNED. It's 4 bytes long and can store numbers up to 4 billion which is more than enough for majority of applications. Using BIGINT (8B - 18446744073709551615 range) is usually an overkill when just starting with your application. Before your database gets too large for INT primary key, you'll need to hire a professional DBA anyway to help you with other issues.

CHAR or BINARY datatypes can be used, when GUID type Primary key is used - such keys make it easier to shard data across multiple database instances, however with MySQL a multi master replication is more often seen.

When using InnoDB tables it's good to remember, that PK will be implicitly the last column in all other indexes created on specific table. This makes it important to use reasonably short datatype for PK (again 4B INT usually does its job well).

Comment: PK is the **last** column in any secondary index in InnoDB.

Comment: Int should work fine if its 4 bytes.  What is the max Length I should use for the field?

Comment: For which field? PK? There's no hard limit, and depending on size of your dataset and the type of queries you run you might get very different results. INT UNSIGNED is pretty safe starting point, and unless you have some specific usage in mind (like data sharding, or offline replication) it should suit you well.

Comment: ZEROFILL is presentation option only. It doesn't change how data is stored in table, so it doesn't affect how PK works either.

Comment: Yes for my PK. I have an attribute called LEN.  If it's an INT UNSIGNED do I even need to use this attribute? Thank you!

Comment: If this attribute can be used to unambiguously identify a row in the table, then you can use it as a natural PK. Personally I am not in favor of natural primary keys though. Experience shows that sooner or later they either need to be changed, or duplicates appear.

Comment: Wait I'm confused. I thought LEN was the maximum character length for the field.

Comment: Ah.. ok... I thought this was in fact a column in your table. No, in case of INTEGER datatype you do not need to specify it's length (it's also for presentation purposes only and will default to 11)

Comment: @Mchl: for an `INT UNSIGNED`, the length will default to 10.

Comment: @spencer7593: That is correct - it's signed int that defaults to 11 (to accomodate for `-` sign) but the bottom line is: it does not matter. Even if you declare the field as `INT(1)` you can still store full range of 32b integers in it.